Google Compute Auto Deletes /etc/init.d/Script Custom Script
I created a my own init.d script: using bash on command shell: sudo nano /etc/init.d/myscript
Here is my script:
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
 start)
  echo "Starting my script"
  /usr/bin/python3 /home/username/PyScripts/myscript.py &
  ;;
 stop)
  echo "Stopping my Script "
  pkill -f /home/username/PyScripts/myscript.py
  ;;
  *)
  echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/myscript {start|stop}"
  exit 1
  ;;
 esac

exit 0

I notice Google Compute VM deletes this script from init.d folder a day later when I try to login into Compute Engine via Command Shell. Why is this happening on the VM?
I really wanted a service that make this script run constantly without Google Compute Engine killing it and deleting it.
Any help on doing this is appreciated. It is kind of suck Google Compute Engine requires paid support to even answer basic question like this!
I am looking for a way to create some type of service that runs my custom python script ALL the time. It seems to be stop running on Google Compute.
